# Is it possible to connect an old IBM 3151 dumb terminal to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: terminal, serial-port

I want to know: If I were to add a serial port to a Raspberry Pi and connectan old IBM 3151 dumb terminal to it; will it be as simple as turning it on and using it? Obviously only for command line access.

[image: Reference photo of an IBM 3151 dumb terminal.]

Comment: more or less: see [support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1000265)

Comment: The RPi should already have a "serial" port, but it is at TTL levels.  You need a 3.3v TTL to RS-232 converter, e.g. a MAX3232 chip.  You will probably have to make your own DB9 to DB25 cable.